# Conformal one to one map from $\{z:\ |z|<1,\ {\bf Im}(z)>0\}$ onto the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Sketch the following region $R$ and find conformal one to one map of $R$ onto the unit disk.

> The exterior of the unit half disk 
>   $$R=\{z:\ |z|<1,\ {\bf Im}(z)>0\}$$
>   (including $\infty$) cut along $[0,−i]$.

I have been able to do the sketching but can anyone please help me with the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

In the سimplest way we see:

the map $\displaystyle z+\frac{1}{z}$ maps $R$ to upper half-plane.

the map $\displaystyle iz$ maps upper half-plane to right half-plane.

the map $\displaystyle \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ maps right half-plane to unit circle.

With composit these maps we have $\displaystyle \frac{-iz^2-i-z}{-iz^2-i+z}$ that maps $R$ to unit circle.

[image]